# How to fix magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool with stability stable

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2.4.4, magento2.4.5, version-upgrade

I am trying to download the upgrade compatibility tool.
Command :
**`composer create-project magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool uct --repository https://repo.magento.com`**

I got below error.

[image]

Comment: can you share which command are you used ?

Comment: composer create-project magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool uct --repository https://repo.magento.com

Comment: try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036036/could-not-find-package-magento-upgrade-compatibility-tool-with-stability-stable

Comment: I tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access Upgrade Compatibility Tool you need to ba an Adobe Commerce subscriber.

It is not available to open source version Magento users.

Answer (score 0):

**The Upgrade Compatibility Tool is available for Adobe Commerce instances only.**

You can check the documentation:- [Upgrade Compatibility Tool](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/use-upgrade-compatibility-tool/run.html?lang=en)